# Preferred Ruby plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ruby-development-tools

RDT (Ruby Development Tool) seems to be the preferred plugin for adding Ruby support to Eclipse. However, I see that the main developer on that project has joined Aptana RadRails. Does this mean that project is no longer up-to-date for Ruby in Eclipse?

If so, which plugin is the preferred and best choice these days?

Comment: Help > Install > Add > http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install. Their site is http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start.

Comment: I prefer DLTK (Dynamic Languages Toolkit)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

<strike>Try the [Dynamic Languages Toolkit](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) for Ruby. It's available from Eclipse's Software Updates panel.</strike>

Update May 2020: Ruby support was dropped in DLTK 6.0 in favour of [Eclipse Solargraph](https://github.com/PyvesB/eclipse-solargraph).

Comment: If anyone needs the main steps to install and use dynamic languages toolkit in eclipse, you can see my answer below.

Comment: I think this is no more working. Getting `No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/` error. Can anyone tell if there is offcial ruby plugin for eclipse?

Comment: Also, you can go to Eclipse->Help -> Marketplace -> search for "ruby" and select ruby DLTS with some version on it.  For details you can visit to this link https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ruby-dltk

Answer (score 18):

Good question.  I've used Aptana/radrails, and that's definitely one to steer clear of.

It writes a database in whatever directory you happen to start Eclipse from, and generally takes over Eclipse, changing a lot of useful key bindings.

One of the most irritating things is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> stops working in Java files, and that's a hotkey I use *all* the time.

I'm looking forward to hearing people's answers on this one, because I'd like to know of a good one.

Comment: RadRails was super buggy for me. But then again...I might not have installed it right.

Comment: Window > Preferences > General > Keys, to change bindings.

Comment: Right, but what are all the bindings it changes? It's just not worth the trouble.

Comment: I faced a problem with Aptana - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213115/eclipse-cannot-see-ruby-perspective-or-interpreter

Answer (score 12):

Looks like the update site is here: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates/

I found it on www.eclipse.org/dltk/install.php

Comment: I tried the following URL, but I got error as below:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Dynamic Languages Toolkit - iTcl Development Tools (Incubation) 0.95.1.v20080903-1434-0AR09oA55S5N9J28GBE (org.eclipse.dltk.itcl.feature.group 0.95.1.v20080903-1434-0AR09oA55S5N9J28GBE)

Answer (score 6):

I faced [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213115/eclipse-cannot-see-ruby-perspective-or-interpreter) after installing aptana studio plugin for Eclipse. So, I decided to try dynamic languages toolkit for eclipse.

If you want to uninstall the aptana plugin: Eclipse > Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software tab > Aptana plugin > Uninstall. This should do a clean, frustration free uninstall.

Now, lets install the DLTK plugin.

Go to link - http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ruby-dltk. Press the green down arrow. copy the link from popup.

[image]

Eclipse > help > install new software > work with = copied link.

Now you see a list of plugins. In that list,expand the Programming Languages > check the box: Dynamic languages toolkit - Ruby Development Tools > press button: next > obvious steps.

After this, install the RubyInstaller for windows at http://rubyinstaller.org/
Find the location of ruby.exe created by this installation. You will need this to set the ruby interpreter when you create your first eclipse ruby project.

Once you successfully create a Ruby project, eclipse asks you if you want to open the ruby perspective. Say ok. To test if it works, create ruby project, then create an empty ruby script inside this project. Then execute this command `puts "hello ruby"` as a ruby script. Enjoy sparkling ruby !

Comment: Coming from using a simple text editor to create apps, I find Eclipse ridiculously difficult to work with. This answer saved me when I was about to throw my machine against a wall. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used Aptana/RadRails in the past and thouroghly enjoyed it.  I suggest giving it a try.  There is a standalone Eclipse plugin available that supports non-Rails projects decently as well if that's what you're going for.

My only experience with Eclipse was through Aptana, however, so there may be other considerations.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK) is the preferred. step-by-step installation in eclipse:

1. Open eclipse
2. Go to **Help -> "Eclipse Marketplace...**"
3. Type DLTK on Find text box and click Go button
4. Click Install button under Ruby (DLTK) section
5. Follow the instruction in eclipse pop-up

Verification of installation after successful installation:

Go to **Window -> Preferences** and you would see "Dynamic Languages" and "Ruby" are enlisted on the left panel