# Eclipse and Ruby installation.. need a help

Tags: ruby, eclipse, ide

I can't install Ruby Eclipse Plugin. I just followed the guide from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE

But this http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/releas URL doesn't work anymore, I think.

I use Windows 7.

Can you help me with Ruby Eclipse configuration?

Comment: I also tried the above URL, but failed. The error is as below:

Unable to read repository at http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/release.
Unable to read repository at http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/release.
http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/release is not a valid repository location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link contains several [Ruby Eclipse plugins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubyeclipse/).

I don't use Eclipse, but I read the best tool for Eclipse is [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails). You might also want to give the [DLTK a try](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524021/preferred-ruby-plugin-for-eclipse)).

Answer (score 1):

You can install "Aptana eclipse plug-in" for Ruby in Eclipse. Please visit the following for details instructions:

http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, http://updatesite.rubypeople.org/release URL doesn't exist anymore. You can install Ruby Eclipse Plugin manually.

Go to "Downloading and Installing Ruby plugin for Eclipse" section by visiting the following URL:

http://beans.seartipy.com/2006/08/12/develop-ruby-applications-using-eclipse-ide/

The steps mentioned there will guide you. Best of luck.