# Eclipse - cannot see ruby perspective or interpreter

Tags: ruby, eclipse

I got the eclipse plugin for ruby from aptana at - http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
My Eclipse = kepler. I cannot see any perspective for Ruby. I cannot even see its interpreter
in my Windows > preferences. I can, however, create ruby projects and .rb files. There is also no
view for Ruby.

What is missing ? I never had this problem when I installed a python plugin in the same eclipse.

When I run a sample ruby script, I get the error `Unable to find a Ruby executable.` The SO posts for this issue did not help. There is already a ruby.exe in my system. I got it when I installed RubyInstaller.

Comment: An alternative to this aptana mess is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524021/preferred-ruby-plugin-for-eclipse/25213384#25213384