# Can a ruby gem/module be added just like a java jar file?

Tags: ruby, eclipse

I use Eclispse Kepler with DLTK plugin for ruby. I am unable to "require" nokogiri module because it cannot be found by eclipse. I tried some gem install command from some website and that did not help. Now, I don't want to use commandline until I first master Ruby programming.

I learned that I can add java jars to my project by creating a lib folder, copying jars to that folder and then adding them all to the build path. So easy, right ?

Can I do the same thing for ruby gems and modules ? Ideally, I'd like to use only the IDE for this instead of using commandline and complext install scripts.

Please help.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to comment on this, but I just have to give you an upvote for your name and profile. You should have asked the question in broken English though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the answer to this question. I not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works for me. Pro developers, can you please review this answer ? So, for now let me give quick guide for this.

1 - Install Eclipse DLTK plugin for Ruby as suggested here - [Preferred Ruby plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524021/preferred-ruby-plugin-for-eclipse)
See the answer with photo, by James.

2 - Next, lets pick a random gem such as nokogiri and download it from rubygems.org. The file name of the Gem tells you which OS its meant for. I use windows 7 64bits. So, I take version with `x64-mingw32`. Here is a sample list of downloads:

```
1.6.4.1 November 7, 2014 java (2.37 MB)
1.6.4.1 November 7, 2014 x64-mingw32 (2.86 MB)
1.6.4.1 November 7, 2014 (8.81 MB)
1.6.4.1 November 7, 2014 x86-mingw32 (3.91 MB)
1.6.4 November 5, 2014 java (2.37 MB)
Show all versions (271 total)
```

3 - AFAIK, eclipse cannot use the gem file as is. You need to unpack it first. Lets say you kept the gem file in c:\RubyGems\extras, and you want to unpack it there itself.

open windows cmd > cd into the above directory > gem unpack nokogiri-1.6.4.1-x64-mingw32.gem > press enter !!!

Now, your gem will be unpacked into a folder `nokogiri-1.6.4.1-x64-mingw32`.

4 - Locate the `nokogiri.rb` file inside the unpacked folder. Its in the lib folder.
Copy the full path of this folder - `c:\RubyGems\extras\nokogiri-1.6.4.1-x64-mingw32\lib`. We need this for eclipse.

5 - Eclipse > create new ruby project > right click project > build path > configure build path > libraries tab > add external source folder > enter the path from step 4 > Ok > ok. You can now use the gem in your project.

6 - Testing if the steps work. Use the code in your project !

```
require 'nokogiri'

puts "Chenqui ! It is work!!!"
```

If the message prints without error, then you are a success ! To see the error you get when the required modules can't be found, add something like this `require 'restclient'`.

Answer (score 5):

If this gem already installed with all dependencies, then you can add it with simple `require` command:

```
require "/path_to_gems/gem_name/lib/gem_name"
```

In my case the command is:

```
require '/Users/yukke/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/lib/nokogiri'
```

Otherwise you can try to require `rubygems` first:

```
require "rubygems"
require "gem-name"
```

Comment: Hmm...I am guessing that there is a folder inside my ruby installation where i can add all "plugin" libraries like nokogiri. Is that correct ? If its so simple, then I could simply go to ruby 2.0 (installed with exe installer) and put the required modules into the right folder. Please advise. Thanks. Chenqui.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest maybe using a different IDE with better Ruby support, such as [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/), which is Eclipse-based but has a lot of additional addons to support Ruby development. You can install Ruby gems in it on the start page, or through the integrated terminal.

Comment: This is why I avoided the aptana studio plugin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524021/preferred-ruby-plugin-for-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command `gem which bundler` you will see the folder gems are installed on your system.
You can copy executables there but it's highly recommended you use gem install on the command line.