# How to find programs in linux when search comes up empty

Tags: ruby, linux, search

I installed Ruby 1.9.1 and verified it is installed.  According to Software Manager it's installed.  Search Ruby or Ruby 1.9.1 comes up empty.  Browsing folders nothing is found either.  How do I find this program and others that are lost in space as well?

Comment: You should go over to SuperUser with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a shell and type in

```
ruby -v
```

If that gives you a version number, then it is successfully installed. To find where the binary is installed, do

```
which ruby
```

This will return the full path of the compiled ruby interpreter.

Comment: Thank You very much.  I found it.  However.  It wouldn't open.  So I tried xdg-open usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 and it came up with. No application is registered as handling this application.  So what application do I need to work with Ruby?

Comment: You don't "open" ruby in a window if that's what you are trying to do. You simply do `ruby myapp.rb`, where the file myapp.rb is a simple text file that you created/populated with any editor of your choice (for example `gedit`). You can also run `irb` which is an interactive prompt where you can test running ruby one-liners.

Comment: Maybe I downloaded the wrong thing.  I want a Ruby IDE.

Comment: There's a ton to choose from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer

Comment: Ok.  Thank You.  I do have Eclipse.  I can write and compile Ruby in that?

Comment: Yes, you can use that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524021/preferred-ruby-plugin-for-eclipse

Comment: P.S - you don't "compile" ruby code. The source code is interpreted at run-time.

Comment: Ok.  Thank You.  I briefly read beginning paragraphs of five Ruby tutorials to find the one I want to use.  However, I feel none of those five are explaining it properly.  It's all, here, write this code, but not... this is what you do with it.  The first one I tried was simply explaining how to do it in dos (before I switched to linux) and no IDE.  Any opinion on the "best" Ruby tutorial?

Comment: I accepted your answer.  I appreciate the help! :)  I would vote for it, but I need 5 reputation points first lol

Comment: Check out the "introduction" section here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info

Answer (score 0):

The command `which ruby` will tell you the location of the `ruby` executable that is run when you type `ruby` into the command line.